# Calculating and Creating a Column for the Range of Another Column Based on ID of Additional Column in R

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the range of years of data collection for different sites. The site identifier is one column, and the year column is another column. The years available are not continuous and collection years differ for sites. I also want to put these range values into another column.

```
head(df)
 MonitoringLocationIdentifier  YEAR
     USGS-260753080113901      1999
     USGS-260533080123701      1999
     USGS-260528080122301      1999
     USGS-260521080122401      1999
     USGS-260530080112101      1999
     USGS-260547080105801      1999
```

From the data.table package I have tried:

```
df$Range <- df[,.(YEAR.Range = range(YEAR)),by=MonitoringLocationIdentifier]

#which returns this error: Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , .(YEAR.Range = range(YEAR)),  : 
  unused argument (by = MonitoringLocationIdentifier)
```

And from the dplyr package I tried:

```
df$Range<-df %>% group_by(MonitoringLocationIdentifier) %>% summarise(Range=range(YEAR)) %>%
  arrange(Range)
#which returns this error: Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `Range` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 2
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces a 2 column data frame whose second column is a 2 column matrix giving the ranges.  No packages are used.

```
ag <- aggregate(DF[2], DF[1], range)
```

If you want a 3 column data frame then:

```
do.call("data.frame", ag)
```

**Note:** The input data frame `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "MonitoringLocationIdentifier  YEAR
 USGS-260753080113901      1999
 USGS-260533080123701      1999
 USGS-260528080122301      1999
 USGS-260521080122401      1999
 USGS-260530080112101      1999
 USGS-260547080105801      1999"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```